# No Merge Request Button for a branch in Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

Newbie in using Git and Gitlab over here

I have a Gitlab setup whereby I have the following branches for a project

> devevlopment (dev) -> consolidation (cons) -> testing (test) ->
>   production (prod) -> master

I would like to merge code on "dev" to "cons".

I see that there is not "Merge Request" button available for "dev"

Why is this the case?

TIA[image]

**Update**

Thanks all for the inputs. I wound up :

1. Creating a project/Repository in a group called MASTER
2. Forking the project/Repository in group MASTER and placing in group PRODUCTION.
3. Continued to do forks that would represent other deployment areas (i.e. test, cons, dev)

This seems to have produced the effect I was looking for - that way - I no longer have branches with :dev, test, prod, etc. under one Repository/Project.

Comment: You can do a merge without a merge request button anyways.

Comment: Well did you create such a pull request?  If not, as @lilezek commented you might have to do a manual merge.

Comment: @lilezek Thx for response.  Of course I can change things manually.  I can click on the "Merge Button" for cons and can change it to "dev". My concern is that if I am in a hurry, I might forget to manually set the source to "dev" by mistake and do something that would be hard to take back (like merging "cons" to "dev" - i.e. cons -> dev)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - are you asking if I did a clone from the "dev" branch?

Comment: @CaseyHarrils merge request are not magic. They are pretty the same than doing the merge manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Merge Request buttons on that screen create a request to merge into your default branch. `dev` *is* your default branch, so no button exists.

If you go to your Merge Requests tab you should be able to create a merge request from your default branch:

1. Navigate to the **Merge Requests** tab
2. Click **New merge request**
3. Select your `dev` branch as the **Source branch**
4. Select your target branch
5. Click **Compare branches and continue**
6. Complete additional details on the **New Merge Request** screen
7. Click **Submit merge request**

Alternatively, as the comments above suggest you could also do a regular Git merge on your local copy and push back up to GitLab.

Comment: @Chrris - thx for your response. The "dev" level is my own (and no one else is supposed to touch it :-) ) I knew one could click on a Merge Button and set the source and target fields manually. You mentioned "dev is your default branch, so no button exists". What I wanted to do was to be able to merge from dev -> cons -> test -> prod. Is there a way to fix the Merge Buttons so that this kind of behavior is possible? Might I ask what people normally do in this case?

Comment: OK, I just made the "master" the default branch and got a "Merge Request" button next to the "dev" area. It seems to be OK for now. TIA